# OpenShift certificates failure

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, openshift

I am facing the following problem when building and deploying my microservice in OpenShift:

- I have microservice A which calls microservice B.
- microservice A and microservice B both have a **Destination CA Cert** configured in their **Route** (termination is reencrypt)
- I am calling microservice A and microservice B from browser, Chrome says my connection to them is secure
- however, when I call microservice B from microservice A, I get the **PKIX path building failed:  sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find  valid certification path to requested target**

Did anyone else encounter this problem? Should I import additional certificates somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

The CA you are using is not trusted by Java.  You need to do something like [this](http://mikepilat.com/2011/05/adding-a-certificate-authority-to-the-java-runtime.html).